# Как прочитать в секции INI файла все значения?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Подскажите, как дополнить класс таким образом, чтобы можно было считать в нужной секции все значения `value` для добавления их в `listBox` при загрузке формы.

Используется класс `IniFile.cs` подробнее: [link](https://gist.github.com/DamianSuess/e8bf4679b201e07757e97aad944e0395)

Содержимое файла `config.ini` выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Визуально, представляю себе код примерно так:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var valueAllRead = ini.ReadAll("GUID") // Чтение всех значений value в секции GUID
   listBox.Items.Add(valueAllRead); // Добавление всех значений в listBox
}
```

p.s. читать после знака равно (`=`) не нужно, только значения `value`

Все, что смог найти по теме вопроса: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7120556/7549532)

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern int GetPrivateProfileSection(string lpAppName, byte[] lpszReturnBuffer, int nSize, string lpFileName);

private List<string> GetKeys(string iniFile, string category)
    {

    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

    GetPrivateProfileSection(category, buffer, 2048, iniFile);
    String[] tmp = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer).Trim('\0').Split('\0');

    List<string> result = new List<string>();

    foreach (String entry in tmp)
    {
        result.Add(entry.Substring(0, entry.IndexOf("="))); // Ошибка здесь
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Что вы передаете в `GetKeys` первым параметром (iniFile)?

Answer (score 0):

У тебя 3 варианта:

1. Воспользоваться WinApi, как описано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14906422/4244707), так как .ini-это формат винды и как следствие есть функции для чтения.

   ```
   [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
   static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string Section, string Key, string Value, string FilePath);

   [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
   static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string Section, string Key, string Default, StringBuilder RetVal, int Size, string FilePath);
   ```
2. Написать свой парсер, благо, структура *.ini-файлов простая
3. либой [INI File](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ini-parser/)

P.S Вопрос такого рода, вроде, задавался, но сам вопрос найти не могу...=(